# FSO to copy save files. VBScript/ASP page using subroutine

Tags: javascript, vbscript, subroutine, filesystemobject

I'm trying to use FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") to copy/save files utilising a ASP utility called 'csImageFile'

At present the FSO code I have is on a separate .asp page. This is called from a page when the user selects an option (using value="xxx.asp..." to call code page).  This works fine.

The problems is that the FSO code page response.redirects to the calling page and the refresh loses data.

I'd like the 'onlclick' of the select/option to call the FSO code by placing the code in a subrouting on the original calling page (hence avoiding the refresh).  I've tried this by various ways without success.  I presently call a js function which itself then calls a VBscript subroutine.  This is may not be correct but I've tried so many permutations I'm a bit lost now.

on page

```
<option onclick="calljsSub()"...
```

the scripts

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function calljsSub(){
    //alert("js called");
    VBFunc();
    }
</script>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub VBFunc()
        SET FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If FSO.FileExists ( "path to file") Then
                Set Image = Server.CreateObject("csImageFile.Manage")
                Image.ReadFile "path to file"
                Image.WriteFile Server.MapPath("path to new file")
        end if
        Set FSO = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The VBScript function appears to do nothing.  Perhaps there is another way of runnning the code without refreshing?? Any advice is welcome.

I'd be very grateful for any advice as I've been trying to solve this since before Christmas.

Mark thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for anyone trying to help.  I've sort this out by calling the asp page through a hidden iframe on the main page.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are mixing up what happens on the client and what happens on the server:

```
click event = client
javascript code = client
VB Script = server
```

You cannot call a function on the server from the client - they're different machines. You need to call a URL, i.e. an ASP page. This ASP page needs to look at the request being made, grab whatever request parameters are sent and decide which code to run based on those parameters - in this case your VBFunc().

This is the most basic functionality of how web pages work:

page -> request -> server -> response (new page)

Yes, you can run the code without refreshing, using AJAX techniques, but try to get the basic working properly first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I thought that was the case but was hoping there was a simple work around.

Comment: On a similar issue, am I able to write to a MySQL database using Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") without calling this code on another .asp page (with consequent refresh) or is this a similar restriction? I'd prefer to call a sub/function on the same page.  I guess this is a no go too?  I'm doing my best to get to grips with this but I'm from old school vb programming. Thanks

Comment: You should invest learning .NET MVC, (not just .NET), if you're stick with Microsoft technologies. Classic ASP is now over 10 years old.

Comment: Thanks for anyone trying to help.  I've sort this out by calling the asp page through a hidden iframe on the main page.  Cheers.